# Binding String Property in Code-Behind TextBlock

Tags: wpf, binding, code-behind

i am trying to binding a very simple property to a TextBlock, but I have to do all in code-behind (C#).

What i am trying to do is:

```
public string SomeText { get; set; }
```

And after I try the Binding on TextBlock:

```
Binding myBinding = new Binding(SomeText);
myTextBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, myBinding);
```

How do I keep the Text property of the TextBlock the same of the Property `SomeText`.

Comment: `Binding myBinding = new Binding(SomeText);` sould be `Binding myBinding = new Binding("SomeText");` Just quote `SomeText`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use BindingOperations

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("SomeText");
binding.Source = sourceObject;  // view model?

BindingOperations.SetBinding(theTextBlock, TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
```

Comment: FrameworkLement has [a wrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.setbinding.aspx) for that, it would be shorter. The only problem here was the setting of the binding path.