# Bind Json data to TextBlock through C# code

Tags: c#, json, xaml

I make my Textblocks in C# code and i want to bind JSON data to it. At this moment i want to do it like this:

```
        if (actualStock == true)
        {
            TextBlock TBActualStock = new TextBlock();
            TBActualStock.Text = "Actuele voorraad: ";
            TBActualStock.FontSize = 18;
            STACKActualStockDeliverTime.Children.Insert(1, TBActualStock);

            TextBlock TBBindActualStock = new TextBlock();
            TBBindActualStock.Text = "{Binding ActualStock}"; //this is where it should bind
            TBBindActualStock.FontSize = 18;
            STACKActualStockDeliverTime2.Children.Insert(1, TBBindActualStock);
        }
```

This is my XAML code:

```
 DataContext="{Binding Item}"
    d:DataContext="{Binding Groups[0].Items[0]}">
    <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/BackGroundGAC.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    </Grid.Background>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="contentRegion">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="STACKActualStockDeliverTime">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="HEADERActualStockDeliverTime" FontSize="24" Text="Voorraad en levertijd"></TextBlock>     
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel  x:Name="STACKActualStockDeliverTime2">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="Headert" FontSize="24" Text=""></TextBlock>


                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
```

Now I want add the Json data to the textblock i make in the C# code. i know in XAML i should use {Binding description} `//description is a part of my json object so that works` But if i do this in C# code it will just set the text to {Binding Description}

Any idea how i can solve this problem?

ps: I need to do it in C# code and not in XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are binding in code you should not be doing like that, just assign the value

[TextBlock.Text Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.text(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
    TextBlock TBBindActualStock = new TextBlock();
    TBBindActualStock.Text =  ActualStock ;
```

If you want to bind in code, use Binding Operation,

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("ActualStock");
binding.Source = sourceObject; 

BindingOperations.SetBinding(TBBindActualStock, TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
```

refered from [Binding String Property in Code-Behind TextBlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131637/binding-string-property-in-code-behind-textblock)

In XAML,

```
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ActualStock}
```

Comment: Well if i make a textblock in XAML and say {Binding ActualStock} it will bind through XAML code, and i don't want that. 
Should i make a new instance of my object in order to obtain ActualStock? As you can see in the XAML file i uploaded, i bind Items to the datacontext. should i do something similar in C#?

Comment: You should make use of INotifyPropertyChanged for your Property

Answer (score 0):

you can use Binding class for it like this

```
Binding myBinding = new Binding("ActualStock");
myBinding.Source = myDataObject;//here is your data source.
TBBindActualStock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, myBinding);
```

Comment: You're in the right direction :) thanks for your help. take a look at the correct answer for the differences.