# Displaying a file in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml

I want to create a program that will enable user to open a file. That would create a new tab and assign a class to that tab that contains over 200 fields of various types (which I have already designed, along with read and write code of the program).

Then I would create an interface that would enable user to change any of that 200 fields.

Does that mean I have to create a property for each and every single of 200 fields that I have in order to bind them with fields?

Is there another way? Is this kind of program more viable for WindowsForms?

It seems a lot easier to do this programmatically instead of using XAML.
Is there a 3rd solution?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for the [PropertyGrid](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PropertyGrid&referringTitle=Home). It may be not as beautiful as you'd expect, but it would cover major of your needs. There're some customizations examples, but it still looks ugly (IMO).

Otherwise you could create a control by yourself. Define deferent templates for various types of your properties. It shouldn't be difficult: some reflection, [create bindings via C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131637/binding-string-property-in-code-behind-textblock), some templates.

Comment: You could also style the `PropertyGrid`, or even write a totally new `ControlTemplate` for it.

Comment: @MikeEason yep, but not sure how pretty it could be.